# Very Slow Response To Enter Key Binding in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, tkinter

So I'm using Python and Tkinter, I'm making a to-do list. Except, there is a very slow wait time when I press ENTER to running the function.

The Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle

'''
Final Version
'''


def delete_all():
    first_listbox.delete(0, END)
    while len(tasks) > 0:
        del tasks[0]

def add(event):
    if entry.get().strip() == '':
        return None
    first_listbox.insert(END, entry.get())
    tasks.append(entry.get())
    entry.delete(0, END)


def delete():
    selection = first_listbox.curselection()
    first_listbox.delete(selection)
    tasks.remove(entry.get())

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, bg='LightBlue')
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, rowspan=10, columnspan=10)


frame.bind('<Enter>', add)

root.geometry('400x400')
root.title('Bad to-do list')
root.configure(bg='LightBlue')

first_listbox = Listbox(frame, width=50, selectmode = BROWSE)
first_listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan = 5, sticky=W)

entry = Entry(frame, width=50)
entry.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, columnspan=2)

#submit_button = Button(frame, text='Insert', command=add)<-- Old Code Before Binding Enter
#submit_button.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W) <-- Old Code Before Binding Enter

delete_button = Button(frame, text='Done', command=delete)
delete_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

delete_all_button = Button(frame, text='Delete All', command=delete_all)
delete_all_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, columnspan=2)



pickle_out = open('to-do-example.pickle', 'rb')
tasks = pickle.load(pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
for item in tasks:
    first_listbox.insert(0, item)




root.mainloop()


pickle_out = open('to-do-example.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(tasks, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

When I run it, it works fine

[image: What It Looks Like]

But, the wait time for adding new tasks after pressing ENTER is terribly slow.
But, strangely, if I use the left mouse click for the binding part instead of the enter key, it works fine responding instantly?

Could someone please explain.

Comment: `<Enter>` is the event for the mouse cursor entering a widget.  `<Return>` is the event for pressing the Enter key on the keyboard.

Comment: You Are Awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from jasonharper...

```
<Enter>
```

is whenever the mouse enters the widget

```
<Return>
```

is the actual enter button